How do I write out data from SQL table using PhP (8.2)
I want to create a main page for my learning site (trying to learn stuff), but I have a problem with (I think) getting response from query.
HTML for getting the table what I want. Value in button is the table name from Database
<body>
  <div class="s">
        <form  action="table.php" method="POST">
          <ul>
           <!-- <li><input class="button" type="submit" name="ok" value="**table name**"></li> -->
                <li><input class="button" type="submit" name="ok" value="name"></li>
                <li><input class="button" type="submit" name="ok" value="exam"></li>
           </ul>
        </form>
  </div>
</body>

PhP
 if (isset($_POST["ok"])) 
    {
        $TableIWant = $_POST["ok"]; //Stores the name of the table
        $servername = "X";
        $username = "X";
        $password = "X";
        $dbname = "X";
        
        //Sql - gets column names?
        $sqlcol = "SELECT CONCAT('',GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME`),'') FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='$dbname' AND `TABLE_NAME`= '$TableIWant'";
        //create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        
        echo "$sqlcol <br>"; // writes out (just for chechk)
        $column = $conn->query($sqlcol);  
        echo "$column <br>";

// after I get column names I go and get the data from database and make table, but I am stuck on getting the column names
    }


(1) You have two submit buttons but both are having the name "ok"?? (2) $column = $conn->query($sqlcol) will not put data directly into $column , if you want to get the data, you need to use FETCH

Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the mysqli documentation and this: How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

This is a response to your answer, as opposed to your original question.
Your current die statements for handling errors will not do anything. As of PHP 8.1.0, the default mysqli_driver::$report_mode is MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT, meaning an exception will be thrown if there is a connection or query error. For more detail on error handling, you might want to read this write up on error handling.
Your "solution" uses an unnecessary separate info schema query to get the column names and it is interpolating variables directly into the SQL. Parameterising this is trivial, and I would suggest that it is even more important to do things "properly" while learning, as it helps you avoid forming bad habits.
$sqlcol = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `columns`
           FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
           WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = ? AND `TABLE_NAME` = ?";
$columns = $conn->execute_query($sqlcol, [$dbname, $TableIWant])->fetch_column();

Instead of the info schema query, you can retrieve the list of columns with mysqli_result::fetch_fields.
// SQL query to fetch data from the specified table
$dataResult = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `$TableIWant`");

// Get columns list from result set
$columns = $dataResult->fetch_fields();

Now that $columns is an array of objects, you would change your column header iteration to:
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo "<th>$column->name</th>";
}

The query above is interpolating $TableIWant directly into the SQL, as the table name cannot be parameterised. Even though this is just for your "learning site", it is another good example of where you should implement some sensible checks. If this was public facing you definitely wouldn't want the end user to grab all the data from any table they want, or to exploit the vulnerability by attempting a SQL Injection attack. So, to make sure the user can only access allowed tables you would have a whitelist, something like:
$tableWhitelist = ['name', 'exam'];

if (isset($_POST['ok']) && in_array($_POST['ok'], $tableWhitelist)) {
    // do stuff
    $TableIWant = $_POST['ok'];
}


Well the solution It is not the best you can do but it works.
<?php
if (isset($_POST["ok"])) {
// Get the table name from POST data
$TableIWant = $_POST["ok"];

// Database connection details
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create a new connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check for connection errors
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// SQL query to get concatenated column names
$sqlcol = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `columns`
           FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
           WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '$dbname' AND `TABLE_NAME` = '$TableIWant'";

// Execute the query to get column names
$result = $conn->query($sqlcol);

if (!$result) {
    die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
}

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($row) {
    // Split the concatenated column names into an array
    $columns = explode(", ", $row['columns']);

    // SQL query to fetch data from the specified table
    $sqlData = "SELECT * FROM `$TableIWant`"; // Query to fetch all data from the specified table

    $dataResult = $conn->query($sqlData); // Execute the query to get data

    if ($dataResult && $dataResult->num_rows > 0) {
        // Start the HTML table with centered alignment
        echo "<table border='1' style='margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;'>";

        // Display the table header with column names
        echo "<tr>"; 
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            echo "<th>$column</th>"; // Table headers for each column
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        // Display each row of data in the table
        while ($dataRow = $dataResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>"; 
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                echo "<td>" . $dataRow[$column] . "</td>"; // Output each data cell
            }
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }

        echo "</table>"; // End the table
    } else {
        echo "No data found in table '$TableIWant'.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No columns found for table '$TableIWant'.";
}

// Close the connection
$conn->close();
} 
?>


As already pointed out in the comments to your question, you should be using parameterised queries and prepared statements. There is no need to run a separate info schema query to get the column names, as they can be retrieved using $dataResult->fetch_fields(); or from the rows in the result set. As the table names cannot be parameterised for your main select query, you should check the value of $_POST["ok"] against an array containing a whitelist of table names.

Yea I probably should but in my database arent any real data and purpose of this is to just to learn how to write data from tables.

It takes no additional effort to do things properly and it will set you up with some good habits to take forward. Bad habits have a tendency to stick, so it is much better to avoid them from the start.

Valid point and a good Idea for next "project/s" (I am going step by step)
